# How to animate group of svg objects along an svg path

Tags: svg, css-animations, svg-animate

I need to animate the alphabet along a path so that it arcs to fit the path as it animates in.

I have tried using the arc path with an animateMotion tag in the hopes that it bends the alphabet group into it, but instead it is following the path while keeping the group of alphabet letters in a straight line.

Is there any way I can achieve this effect?

https://codepen.io/Finches/pen/vYgMBwW

Edit to include mandatory cody snippet (easier to just get the full svg from the codepen):

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="1359px"
 height="396px" viewBox="0 0 1359 396" style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new 0 0 1359 396;" xml:space="preserve">
```

Comment: I suppose you should add <animateMotion> to every letter separately instead of the whole block

Answer (score 3):

You will need to animate each letter using the same animation and a delay declared with the begin attribute. In the next example I'm animating only the letters A B and C.

If you use the same path for your animation you can use a `<mpath xlink:href="#path"></mpath>` element to point the path you want to use and save the original path in the defs

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1359 396" style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new 0 0 1359 396;" xml:space="preserve">

  <style type="text/css">
    .st0 {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000000;
      stroke-width: 2;
      stroke-miterlimit: 10;
    }

    .st1 {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000000;
      stroke-width: 2;
      stroke-miterlimit: 10;
      stroke-dasharray: 11.9626, 11.9626;
    }

    .st2 {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000000;
      stroke-width: 2;
      stroke-miterlimit: 10;
      stroke-dasharray: 11.9189, 11.9189;
    }

    .st3 {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000000;
      stroke-width: 2;
      stroke-miterlimit: 10;
      stroke-dasharray: 6.0125, 6.0125;
    }
  </style>

  <defs>

    <path id="path" d="M1214.7,330.9L1214.7,330.9C1214.7,148.2,1047.5,0,841.1,0L373.6,0C167.2,0,0,148.2,0,330.9v0" />
  </defs>
  <path class="st0" d="M1215.7,395c0-147.7-135.7-267.9-302.4-267.9H445.7C279,127.1,143.3,247.2,143.3,395H1
    c0-53.2,11.8-104.8,35-153.4c22.4-46.9,54.5-89,95.3-125.2S219.6,51.8,272.6,32C327.5,11.4,385.7,1,445.7,1h467.6
    c60,0,118.3,10.4,173.1,31c53,19.8,100.5,48.2,141.3,84.4s72.9,78.3,95.3,125.2c23.2,48.6,35,100.2,35,153.4L1215.7,395z" />
  <g>
    <g>
      <path class="st0" d="M1230.6,395c0-2,0-4-0.1-6" />
      <path class="st1" d="M1230,377c-10.2-156-152.9-263.4-316.7-263.4H445.7c-165.9,0-310.1,110.2-317,269.4" />
      <path class="st0" d="M128.5,389c0,2-0.1,4-0.1,6" />
    </g>
  </g>
  <g>
    <g>
      <path class="st0" d="M16.5,395c0.1-2,0.2-4,0.3-6" />
      <path class="st2" d="M17.6,377.1c3.6-43,14.5-92.7,32.4-130.2c21.6-45.3,52.6-86,92-120.9c39.4-34.9,85.3-62.3,136.5-81.5
            c53-19.9,109.2-29.9,167.2-29.9h467.6c58,0,114.2,10.1,167.2,29.9c51.1,19.2,97.1,46.6,136.5,81.5c39.4,34.9,70.4,75.6,92,120.9
            c18.7,39.2,29.7,91.8,32.9,136.2" />
      <path class="st0" d="M1342.2,389c0.1,2,0.2,4,0.3,6" />
    </g>
  </g>
  <g>
    <g>
      <path class="st0" d="M1286.9,395L1286.9,395c0-1,0-2,0-3" />
      <path class="st3" d="M1286.7,385.9C1281.3,207.3,1116.2,64,913.3,64H445.7C241.7,64,75.8,209,72.2,388.9" />
      <path class="st0" d="M72.2,392c0,1,0,2,0,3v0" />
    </g>
  </g>

  <!-- Alphabet  -->
  <g>

    <g id="a" transform="translate(-35,-35)">
      <animateMotion dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite">
        <mpath xlink:href="#path"></mpath>
      </animateMotion>
      <rect x="1" y="1" class="st0" width="69.2" height="69.2" />
      <path d="M14.7,52.2L31.8,7.6h6.4l18.3,44.6h-6.7l-5.2-13.5H25.9L21,52.2H14.7z M27.6,33.9h15.1L38,21.5c-1.4-3.8-2.5-6.8-3.2-9.3
            c-0.6,2.9-1.4,5.7-2.4,8.5L27.6,33.9z" />
    </g>

    <g id="b" transform="translate(-121,-35)">
      <animateMotion dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="1s">
        <mpath xlink:href="#path"></mpath>
      </animateMotion>
      <rect x="85.9" y="1" class="st0" width="69.2" height="69.2" />
      <path d="M104.2,52.3V7.7h16.7c3.4,0,6.1,0.5,8.2,1.4c2.1,0.9,3.7,2.3,4.8,4.2c1.2,1.9,1.8,3.8,1.8,5.9c0,1.9-0.5,3.7-1.6,5.4
            s-2.6,3-4.7,4.1c2.7,0.8,4.8,2.1,6.2,4c1.4,1.9,2.2,4.2,2.2,6.8c0,2.1-0.4,4-1.3,5.8c-0.9,1.8-2,3.2-3.3,4.2
            c-1.3,1-2.9,1.7-4.9,2.2c-2,0.5-4.4,0.7-7.2,0.7H104.2z M110.1,26.5h9.6c2.6,0,4.5-0.2,5.6-0.5c1.5-0.4,2.6-1.2,3.4-2.2
            c0.8-1,1.1-2.3,1.1-3.9c0-1.5-0.4-2.8-1.1-3.9s-1.7-1.9-3-2.3S122.2,13,119,13h-8.9V26.5z M110.1,47.1h11.1c1.9,0,3.2-0.1,4-0.2
            c1.4-0.2,2.5-0.6,3.4-1.2s1.7-1.4,2.3-2.5c0.6-1.1,0.9-2.3,0.9-3.8c0-1.7-0.4-3.1-1.3-4.3s-2-2.1-3.5-2.6s-3.7-0.7-6.5-0.7h-10.3
            V47.1z" />
    </g>

    <g id="c" transform="translate(-209.4,-35)">
      <animateMotion dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="2s">
        <mpath xlink:href="#path"></mpath>
      </animateMotion>
      <rect x="174.4" y="1.1" class="st0" width="69.2" height="69.2" />
      <path d="M224.8,36.7l5.9,1.5c-1.2,4.8-3.5,8.5-6.7,11.1c-3.2,2.5-7.1,3.8-11.8,3.8c-4.8,0-8.7-1-11.7-2.9c-3-2-5.3-4.8-6.9-8.5
            c-1.6-3.7-2.4-7.7-2.4-12c0-4.6,0.9-8.7,2.7-12.2c1.8-3.5,4.3-6.1,7.6-7.9S208.4,7,212.3,7c4.5,0,8.2,1.1,11.3,3.4
            c3,2.3,5.2,5.5,6.4,9.6l-5.8,1.4c-1-3.2-2.5-5.6-4.5-7.1c-2-1.5-4.4-2.2-7.4-2.2c-3.4,0-6.3,0.8-8.6,2.5s-3.9,3.8-4.9,6.6
            c-0.9,2.8-1.4,5.6-1.4,8.6c0,3.8,0.6,7.1,1.7,9.9c1.1,2.8,2.8,4.9,5.2,6.3c2.3,1.4,4.9,2.1,7.6,2.1c3.3,0,6.1-1,8.4-2.9
            C222.4,43.3,224,40.4,224.8,36.7z" />
    </g>

  </g>

</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

For solution one can use SVG: [textPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/textPath)

This will significantly reduce the code, since there will be only one path and the same animation for the movement of letters along this path.

- Each letter of the alphabet is wrapped in tags - `<tspan  dx="0" dy="30">A</tspan>`
- The spacing between letters can be adjusted with the `dx` parameter
  or with `letter-spacing = "0.18em"`
  I chose `letter-spacing` as Firefox and Chrome do different spacing adjustments with `dx` and `dy`.
- Since initially all the letters of the alphabet do not fit on the
  traffic route, it must be made longer:

[image]

Below is the complete code, the animation of the movement of the letters will start after the click:

```css
.container {
     width:100vw;
     height:100vh;
     }
    .st0 {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000000;
      stroke-width: 3;
      stroke-miterlimit: 10;
    }

    .st1 {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000000;
      stroke-width: 2;
      stroke-miterlimit: 10;
      stroke-dasharray: 11.9626, 11.9626;
    }

    .st2 {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000000;
      stroke-width: 2;
      stroke-miterlimit: 10;
      stroke-dasharray: 11.9189, 11.9189;
    }

    #st3 {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #565656;
      stroke-width: 2;
      stroke-miterlimit: 10;
      stroke-dasharray: 6.0125, 6.0125;
    }
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1359 396" style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new 0 0 1359 396;" xml:space="preserve">
  
    <path  id="st3"  d="m73.1 2823.3 0-2367.5L72.2 388.9c0 0 6.7-64.1 17.1-94.2 10.2-29.6 24.9-58 43.6-83.1 19-25.4 42.8-47.4 68.1-66.5 25-18.8 52.8-33.9 81.4-46.5 29.6-13.1 79.6-27.3 92.5-29.8 8.5-1.7 568.1-7.2 597.3-1.8 30.1 5.5 64 14.6 94.4 26.7 25.5 10.2 50.3 22.8 73.1 38.2 25.4 17.2 49.5 36.9 69.8 59.8 21.2 23.9 40.8 50.3 53.2 79.7C1277.7 307.4 1286.7 385.9 1286.7 385.9" />
   
  <!-- Alphabet  -->
   <text font-size="100px" fill="#565656" letter-spacing="0.18em">
     <textPath xlink:href="#st3" startOffset="100%" >
        <tspan  dx="0" dy="30"> A</tspan>
         <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> B</tspan>
           <tspan   dx="0" dy="0"> C</tspan>
            <tspan  dx="0" dy="0"> D</tspan> 
             <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> E</tspan>   
              <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> F</tspan>
               <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> G</tspan>
                <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> H</tspan>  
                 <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> I</tspan>
                  <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> J</tspan>
                 <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> K</tspan>
                <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> L</tspan> 
               <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> M</tspan>  
              <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> N</tspan>
             <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> O</tspan>
            <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> P</tspan>
           <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> Q</tspan> 
          <tspan dx="0" dy="0">R</tspan> 
         <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> S</tspan>
        <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> T</tspan>
       <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> U</tspan> 
      <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> V</tspan>      
     <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> W</tspan>
      <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> X</tspan>
       <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> Y</tspan>
        <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> Z</tspan>    
        <animate  attributeName="startOffset" from="100%" to="-20%" begin="svg1.click" dur="20s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
        </text>
    </textPath> 
    
  <path class="st0" d="M1215.7,395c0-147.7-135.7-267.9-302.4-267.9H445.7C279,127.1,143.3,247.2,143.3,395H1     c0-53.2,11.8-104.8,35-153.4c22.4-46.9,54.5-89,95.3-125.2S219.6,51.8,272.6,32C327.5,11.4,385.7,1,445.7,1h467.6     c60,0,118.3,10.4,173.1,31c53,19.8,100.5,48.2,141.3,84.4s72.9,78.3,95.3,125.2c23.2,48.6,35,100.2,35,153.4L1215.7,395z" />
     
      <path class="st1" d="M1230,377c-10.2-156-152.9-263.4-316.7-263.4H445.7c-165.9,0-310.1,110.2-317,269.4" />
         
      <path class="st2" d="M17.6,377.1c3.6-43,14.5-92.7,32.4-130.2c21.6-45.3,52.6-86,92-120.9c39.4-34.9,85.3-62.3,136.5-81.5c53-19.9,109.2-29.9,167.2-29.9h467.6c58,0,114.2,10.1,167.2,29.9c51.1,19.2,97.1,46.6,136.5,81.5c39.4,34.9,70.4,75.6,92,120.9
            c18.7,39.2,29.7,91.8,32.9,136.2" /> 
     <rect x="0" y="398" width="1400" height="800" fill="white" />      
    </svg>
```

In the question, each letter is wrapped in a frame.

This can be solved by using [Unicode characters](https://unicode-table.com/ru/sets/symbols-for-nickname/#latin-letters-in-a-circle), which will replace Latin letters with a frame around the letter. **`&#9398;`** - **Ⓐ**

Since this is essentially a font, you can style it: setting the size, color, etc.

The rest is the same as in the first example. Only letters are replaced with unicode characters

```css
.container {
     width:100vw;
     height:100vh;
     }
    .st0 {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000000;
      stroke-width: 3;
      stroke-miterlimit: 10;
    }

    .st1 {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000000;
      stroke-width: 2;
      stroke-miterlimit: 10;
      stroke-dasharray: 11.9626, 11.9626;
    }

    .st2 {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000000;
      stroke-width: 2;
      stroke-miterlimit: 10;
      stroke-dasharray: 11.9189, 11.9189;
    }

    #st3 {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #565656;
      stroke-width: 2;
      stroke-miterlimit: 10;
      stroke-dasharray: 6.0125, 6.0125;
    }
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1359 396" style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new 0 0 1359 396;" xml:space="preserve">
  
    <path  id="st3"  d="m73.1 2823.3 0-2367.5L72.2 388.9c0 0 6.7-64.1 17.1-94.2 10.2-29.6 24.9-58 43.6-83.1 19-25.4 42.8-47.4 68.1-66.5 25-18.8 52.8-33.9 81.4-46.5 29.6-13.1 79.6-27.3 92.5-29.8 8.5-1.7 568.1-7.2 597.3-1.8 30.1 5.5 64 14.6 94.4 26.7 25.5 10.2 50.3 22.8 73.1 38.2 25.4 17.2 49.5 36.9 69.8 59.8 21.2 23.9 40.8 50.3 53.2 79.7C1277.7 307.4 1286.7 385.9 1286.7 385.9" />
   
  <!-- Alphabet  -->
   <text font-size="100px" fill="#565656">
     <textPath xlink:href="#st3" startOffset="100%" >
        <tspan  dx="0" dy="30"> &#9398;</tspan>
         <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> &#9399;</tspan>
           <tspan   dx="0" dy="0"> &#9400;</tspan>
            <tspan  dx="0" dy="0"> &#9401;</tspan> 
             <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> &#9402;</tspan>   
              <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> &#9403;</tspan>
               <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> &#9404;</tspan>
                <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> &#9405;</tspan>  
                 <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> &#9406;</tspan>
                  <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> &#9407;</tspan>
                 <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> &#9408;</tspan>
                <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> &#9409;</tspan> 
               <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> &#9410;</tspan>    
              <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> &#9411;</tspan>
             <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> &#9412;</tspan>
            <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> &#9413;</tspan>
           <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> &#9414;</tspan> 
          <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> &#9415;</tspan> 
         <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> &#9416;</tspan>
        <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> &#9417;</tspan>
       <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> &#9418;</tspan> 
      <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> &#9419;</tspan>    
     <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> &#9420;</tspan>
      <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> &#9421;</tspan>
       <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> &#9422;</tspan>
        <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> &#9423;</tspan>      
        <animate  attributeName="startOffset" from="100%" to="-20%" begin="svg1.click" dur="20s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
        </text>
    </textPath> 
    
  <path class="st0" d="M1215.7,395c0-147.7-135.7-267.9-302.4-267.9H445.7C279,127.1,143.3,247.2,143.3,395H1     c0-53.2,11.8-104.8,35-153.4c22.4-46.9,54.5-89,95.3-125.2S219.6,51.8,272.6,32C327.5,11.4,385.7,1,445.7,1h467.6     c60,0,118.3,10.4,173.1,31c53,19.8,100.5,48.2,141.3,84.4s72.9,78.3,95.3,125.2c23.2,48.6,35,100.2,35,153.4L1215.7,395z" />
     
      <path class="st1" d="M1230,377c-10.2-156-152.9-263.4-316.7-263.4H445.7c-165.9,0-310.1,110.2-317,269.4" />
         
      <path class="st2" d="M17.6,377.1c3.6-43,14.5-92.7,32.4-130.2c21.6-45.3,52.6-86,92-120.9c39.4-34.9,85.3-62.3,136.5-81.5c53-19.9,109.2-29.9,167.2-29.9h467.6c58,0,114.2,10.1,167.2,29.9c51.1,19.2,97.1,46.6,136.5,81.5c39.4,34.9,70.4,75.6,92,120.9
            c18.7,39.2,29.7,91.8,32.9,136.2" /> 
     <rect x="0" y="398" width="1400" height="800" fill="white" />      
    </svg>
```

*An example of styling individual letters*

For the unicode character of the letter **A** in a circle - **Ⓐ**

`<tspan dx="0" dy="30"  style="fill:red; font-size:120px;"> &#9398;</tspan>`

```css
.container {
     width:100vw;
     height:100vh;
     }
    .st0 {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000000;
      stroke-width: 3;
      stroke-miterlimit: 10;
    }

    .st1 {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000000;
      stroke-width: 2;
      stroke-miterlimit: 10;
      stroke-dasharray: 11.9626, 11.9626;
    }

    .st2 {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000000;
      stroke-width: 2;
      stroke-miterlimit: 10;
      stroke-dasharray: 11.9189, 11.9189;
    }

    #st3 {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #565656;
      stroke-width: 2;
      stroke-miterlimit: 10;
      stroke-dasharray: 6.0125, 6.0125;
    }
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1359 396" style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new 0 0 1359 396;" xml:space="preserve">
  
    <path  id="st3"  d="m73.1 2823.3 0-2367.5L72.2 388.9c0 0 6.7-64.1 17.1-94.2 10.2-29.6 24.9-58 43.6-83.1 19-25.4 42.8-47.4 68.1-66.5 25-18.8 52.8-33.9 81.4-46.5 29.6-13.1 79.6-27.3 92.5-29.8 8.5-1.7 568.1-7.2 597.3-1.8 30.1 5.5 64 14.6 94.4 26.7 25.5 10.2 50.3 22.8 73.1 38.2 25.4 17.2 49.5 36.9 69.8 59.8 21.2 23.9 40.8 50.3 53.2 79.7C1277.7 307.4 1286.7 385.9 1286.7 385.9" />
   
  <!-- Alphabet  -->
   <text font-size="100px" fill="#565656">
     <textPath xlink:href="#st3" startOffset="100%" >
        <tspan  dx="0" dy="30"  style="fill:red; font-size:120px;"> &#9398;</tspan>
         <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> &#9399;</tspan>
           <tspan   dx="0" dy="0"> &#9400;</tspan>
            <tspan  dx="0" dy="0"> &#9401;</tspan> 
             <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> &#9402;</tspan>   
              <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> &#9403;</tspan>
               <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> &#9404;</tspan>
                <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> &#9405;</tspan>  
                 <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> &#9406;</tspan>
                  <tspan dx="0" dy="0" style="fill:dodgerblue; font-size:120px;"> &#9407;</tspan>
                 <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> &#9408;</tspan>
                <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> &#9409;</tspan> 
               <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> &#9410;</tspan>    
              <tspan dx="0" dy="0" style="fill:yellowgreen; font-size:120px;"> &#9411;</tspan>
             <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> &#9412;</tspan>
            <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> &#9413;</tspan>
           <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> &#9414;</tspan> 
          <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> &#9415;</tspan> 
         <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> &#9416;</tspan>
        <tspan dx="0" dy="0" style="fill:gold; font-size:120px;"> &#9417;</tspan>
       <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> &#9418;</tspan> 
      <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> &#9419;</tspan>    
     <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> &#9420;</tspan>
      <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> &#9421;</tspan>
       <tspan dx="0" dy="0"> &#9422;</tspan>
        <tspan dx="0" dy="0" style="fill:crimson; font-size:120px;"> &#9423;</tspan>       
        <animate  attributeName="startOffset" from="100%" to="-20%" begin="svg1.click" dur="20s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
        </text>
    </textPath> 
    
  <path class="st0" d="M1215.7,395c0-147.7-135.7-267.9-302.4-267.9H445.7C279,127.1,143.3,247.2,143.3,395H1     c0-53.2,11.8-104.8,35-153.4c22.4-46.9,54.5-89,95.3-125.2S219.6,51.8,272.6,32C327.5,11.4,385.7,1,445.7,1h467.6     c60,0,118.3,10.4,173.1,31c53,19.8,100.5,48.2,141.3,84.4s72.9,78.3,95.3,125.2c23.2,48.6,35,100.2,35,153.4L1215.7,395z" />
     
      <path class="st1" d="M1230,377c-10.2-156-152.9-263.4-316.7-263.4H445.7c-165.9,0-310.1,110.2-317,269.4" />
         
      <path class="st2" d="M17.6,377.1c3.6-43,14.5-92.7,32.4-130.2c21.6-45.3,52.6-86,92-120.9c39.4-34.9,85.3-62.3,136.5-81.5c53-19.9,109.2-29.9,167.2-29.9h467.6c58,0,114.2,10.1,167.2,29.9c51.1,19.2,97.1,46.6,136.5,81.5c39.4,34.9,70.4,75.6,92,120.9
            c18.7,39.2,29.7,91.8,32.9,136.2" /> 
     <rect x="0" y="398" width="1400" height="800" fill="white" />      
    </svg>
```